# Should I tell my old supervisor that I am re-applying to the company?

Tags: applications, employer-relations, references

I am a recent graduate of aerospace engineering and am considering both applying to masters study or go to work. I have recently submitted an application to a job in a company that I have been an intern with two years ago. I have kept my connection with the people in the company and have recently asked my old supervisor to write me a reference letter for graduate school application. [see this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/184726/how-to-ask-my-former-employer-whether-he-finished-my-reference-letter-or-not)

Should I told him that I am applying for a position in the company?

Additom: should I tell my old-coworkers that I am applying that position? Would they understand that I am just keeping all my options open?

Comment: Yes. No. Does it matter? What's your concern?

Comment: I suppose the company is going to see the name on the reference letter. Maybe best to give them a heads up as courtesy as they may be approached.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It seems that the reference letter is for a different place, which raises the issue if the supervisor may raise an alarm about the OP being a risk of leaving the job. That is the only possible downside that I could see.

Comment: @SJuan76 My interpretation is that the OP just graduated and they are not correctly employed by anyone.

Comment: I am not currently employed by anyone or have a post-grad offer yet. I am just worry that my supervisor may think that I am not that interested in this position because I am also applying for grad school, but the reality is that I just want to have more options

Comment: Yes, you should tell him about it. This can only help you, and will not hurt your chance.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but adjacent: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/183318/124857

Answer (score 7):

You are applying to your old employer.

That means that both from your resume and their records, they will know who your worked with. It is likely that they will ask your supervisor for his opinion. And even if they don't, it is possible that your supervisor will get word of your application.

So in this case, I think it is better to take the initiative and control the information flow. If you contact your supervisor, you can tell him that your priority is the job. Otherwise, he will be left guessing.

Of course, if you do that and in the end choose not to get the job, you will probably have burnt some bridges.

Also, unless there is some justification, I would not insist much on getting the recommendation letter, as it could make you to seem to be insincere. A valid justification could be something outside your control (e.g. that if you do not submit by a fixed date the school will no longer accept it until next year).